# How to access deep values from a particular column of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have the following `array` that I converted from a JSON response of the `WP REST API`:

```
[
    [
        'id' => 6,
        'convite_id' => [4],
        'nome_do_convidado' => 'John Doe',
        'email_do_convidado' => ['johndoe@gmail.com', 'another@example'],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'convite_id' => [4],
        'nome_do_convidado' => 'Lorem',
        'email_do_convidado' => ['lorem@gmail.com'],
    ],
]
```

And I'm trying to loop the `email_do_convidado` value as:

- johndoe@gmail.com
- lorem@gmail.com

I've tried with `foreach()` loop and just get the last one, and now I've tried with `while()` and get one result too, follow my script:

```
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($myArray) )
    echo $val['email_do_convidado'][$key];
```

And the result is:

`johndoe@gmail.com`

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: 1.) Loop through the outer array
2.) Within that element, you can now access `email_do_convidado`
3.) If there is always just one element, access the index `0`

Comment: What is your final goal. To get all the emails you could have on `email_do_convidado` ? Or just the first?

Comment: `while (list ($key, $val) = each ($myArray) )` is a 15-years old deprecated way to write `foreach ($myArray as $key => $val)`

Comment: `each()` has even been deprecated in PHP 7.2

Comment: @EstebanGarcia get all emails :)

Comment: @TobiasF.

the tip number 3 solve the problem, because yes, always will be just one element, thanks!

Comment: @DaniloP.daSilva if you'll always have just one element, then why use an array?

Comment: @EstebanGarcia It's a dump from the WP REST API, I don't control the entire array. I just need access a part of the data :( It was in JSON, then I convert to PHP Array to use PHPMailer to send those emails through a loop.

Comment: The other two solutions are actually better than your accepted answer because each email subarray will only contain one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not quite clear, what i understand is that u want the first email of each element, if thats the case u could do this

```
foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value[email_do_convidado][0];
}
```

On the other hand if u have several emails inside "email_do_convidado" u could loop that other array

```
foreach($array as $value){
    foreach($value[email_do_convidado] as $email){
        echo $email;
    }
}
```

Or if u dont want to use a foreach inside a foreach u can

```
//inside the first foreach.
$emails = implode(',', $value[email_do_convidado]);
//and the u echo $emails
echo $emails;
```

Hope my answer helps u.

Answer (score 2):

Try with a foreach instead of a while. You can extract all the emails by merging all arrays into a final output.

```
$emails = [];
foreach($myArray as $entry){
  $emails = array_merge($emails, $entry['email_do_convidado']);
}

var_dump($emails);
```

I assume you'll want to do something afterwards will all the emails. I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The values you are seeking are in:

```
$myArray[0]['email_do_convidado'][0]
$myArray[1]['email_do_convidado'][0]
```

Your code is:

```
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($myArray) ) {
   echo $val['email_do_convidado'][$key]; 
}
```

(slightly amended to better style)

So your code is trying to retrieve

```
$myArray[0]['email_do_convidado'][0]
$myArray[1]['email_do_convidado'][1]
```

The latter doesn't exist. So I'm afraid you have failed on multiple levels:

- your code doesn't do what you intend
- your error reporting is not working (PHP is throwing a warning about this you are not seeing)
- you haven't attempted to instrument your code to see what's happening (simply putting "email=" before the value in your echo statement would have revealed this).

Try:

```
echo $val['email_do_convidado'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

A `foreach()` loop will allow array data to be unpacked into variables use array destructuring syntax, but the example below will only get the first email from each subset.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/drauQ))

```
foreach ($array as ['email_do_convidado' => [$email]]) {
    echo "$email\n";
}
```

Result:

```
johndoe@gmail.com
lorem@gmail.com
```

If your input array had more than one email per subset, you'd need a nested iterator like: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/utXkE))

```
foreach ($array as ['email_do_convidado' => $emails]) {
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        echo "$email\n";
    }
}
```

---

If you want to merely fetch all of the emails as a delimited string, you can use functional-style programming to isolate a column of values, flatten the results, then implode. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/s918i))

```
echo implode(
         "\n",
         array_merge(
             ...array_column(
                 $array,
                 'email_do_convidado'
             )
         )
     );
```